# jQuery - Refering to a specific row in a table

Tags: jquery, hide, selector

I have a table and can count the number of rows using `var count = $("table tr").length;`

Basically, I have up and down arrow controls to reorder the rows in the table.  I do not want the down arrow to appear for the last row and similarly the up arrow to appear for the top row.

Is there a way to refer to specific rows in the table so that I can prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("table tr:first")` and `$("table tr:last")` will return the first and last rows respectively.

Answer (score 1):

a jQuery object is an array of all matching elements, so...

```
var rows = $("table tr");
var firstRow = rows[0];
var lastRow = rows[rows.length - 1];
```

Comment: Thanks.
The last thing I'm still slightly confused about is combining explicit selectors with variables. eg

$(lastRow "img").hide();

Answer (score 0):

I believe the selector itself $(...) returns an array, so you should be able to iterate through all objects in your script.